# Does minitest provide a "test" directive?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest, testunit

In Rails I can use the `test` keyword for my tests which I find very attractive and a bettter choice to Rspec's verbosity.

Example:

```
class TestMyClass < ActionController::TestCase
  test 'one equals one' do
    assert 1 == 1
  end
end
```

At the moment I am creating a gem and I want to follow the same way for my tests - by using the `test` method. I tried inheriting from Minitest and UnitTest and the latter seems to work. However I was under the impression that Rails uses Minitest. So does Minitest actually provide a `test` directive?

This works:

```
class TestMyClass < Test::Unit::TestCase
  test 'one equals one' do
    assert 1 == 1
  end
end
```

This gives me "wrong number of arguments for test":

```
class TestMyClass < Minitest:Test
  test 'one equals one' do
    assert 1 == 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

No, Minitest runs ordinary methods with names started from 'test_'.

Method `test` from ActionController::TestCase is provided by Rails and works as a simple wrap for 'test_*' methods. It converts this

```
test 'truish' do
  assert true
end
```

to this

```
def test_truish
  assert true
end
```

Also it checks if the body of the test was defined, if it wasn't, it will show an error message.